# Room - Synchronous @Delete all

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

Suppose we'd like to replace all items in Android Room DB in the **simplest** possible way. What would be the approach to this task?

Is `@Query("DELETE FROM user")` synchronous or asynchronous in this case?
Is using `@Transaction` a viable solution?

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    companion object {
        fun replaceAll(instance: UserDao, users: List<User>) { 
            instance.clearEntireTable() // possibly asynchronous ? 
            insertAll(instance, users) // synchronous
        }

        private fun insertAll(instance: UserDao, users: List<User>) = users.forEach { instance.insert(it) }
    }

    @Query("DELETE FROM user")
    fun clearEntireTable()

    @Insert
    fun insert(user: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Transaction
fun replaceUsers(users: List<User>) {
    clearEntireTable()
    insertAllUsers(users)
}
```

and also you need this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAllUsers(users: List<User>)
```

And don't put it in the companion object.

What's inside replaceUsers will be synchronous that means that it will first delete all of them and put the new ones. But the result is async because Room doesn't allow you to query on mainThread.

Answer (score 1):

> Is @Query("DELETE FROM user") synchronous or asynchronous in this case?

You are not returning a reactive type (`LiveData`, `Single`, etc.), and you are not implementing a `suspend` function. Hence, this is synchronous.

> Is using @Transaction a viable solution?

It would not be necessary here.

Comment: Assuming `clearEntireTable()` and `insertAll()` **were** both `suspend` functions and called after each other inside a coroutine, wouldn't they still be synchronous? (i.o.w. the first one to be called will suspend the coroutine until completed and then start with the next?)

Comment: @Wess: That probably depends on the dispatcher for the coroutine. I recommend you ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing what you want to do.